# How to continually compare the current time with a timestamp in firebase?

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, timer, tableview

Currently, there is an expiration date in the database. I would like the app to delete the post after the expiration date is passed, even while the user is currently using the app. Currently, the code checks the feed, collects the time, and if the time is less than the current time, the post is deleted from the feed. However, this does not continually compare the time; rather, it only compares the current time with the time in the database only when the value in the database updates or the app is restarted. How can I make it such that the app will continually compare the time interval since 1970 with the time in the database, even while the app is running? I.e even when the user is using the app, if the current time is greater than the expiration time it will delete it from the database?

```swift
func deletePosts() {
    let userID = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid
    let deletionReference = Database.database().reference().child("feeds").child(userID!)
    deletionReference.observe(.childAdded) { (snapshot) in

        let feedPostID = snapshot.key
        print(feedPostID)
        let deletionPostTimeReference = Database.database().reference().child("postStatus").child(feedPostID)
        deletionPostTimeReference.observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in
               print("damn")
            if let value = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary {
                print("shit")
            let timeOfDeletion = value["timeOfDeletion"] as? Int ?? 0
                print(timeOfDeletion)
            if timeOfDeletion == 0 {
                print("we aint deleting")
            }
            else {
                print("time TO DELETE")
                let date = Date()
                let currentTime = UInt64(floor(date.timeIntervalSince1970 * 1000))
                if currentTime >= timeOfDeletion {
                    deletionReference.child(feedPostID).removeValue()
                    if let index = self.postList.index(where: {$0.postID == feedPostID}) {
                        self.postList.remove(at: index)
                        self.orderedPostList = self.postList.sorted(by: { $0.revealDate! > $1.revealDate! })

                        self.tableView.reloadData()
                    }
                }

            }
            }
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: So much nested if statements o.O

Comment: That's true, however a lot of them are mainly to safely unwrap things.

Comment: One options is to use a polling method with a timer in your app. For example, every 5 minutes the timer will fire and call code that does the comparison and delete outdated posts. However, that's kinda '1980's' (70's?). A better option is to utilize a [cron job](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2017/03/how-to-schedule-cron-jobs-with-cloud.html) that fires a cloud function in firebase that removes out of date messages.

Comment: @Jay, I did look at polling at it seemed interesting. Cron jobs however add more complexity to the app. I was thinking of adding a timer that runs a function every two seconds in order to compare the times from an array with the current time. Would this be reasonable?

Comment: Hard to say if it's reasonable as it depends on your use case. While polling on the surface seems simple, there are downsides; what if the user is logged out of the app? If several users have the app who is in control? If your running this on an iOS Device, having a timer run every two seconds non stop can be a drain on the battery. The Cron with a Firebase cloud function is a pretty rock solid solution that, once you've gone through the tutorial, will not be hard to implement and will occupy the least bandwidth and have the lowest impact on your app and devices.